# Strange vertical black stripes

Tags: rendering, glass

I'm new to Blender fluid simulation and want to fill a cylinder with water.

As you can see in the following image, it fills up the cylinder, but on the rendering result, there are strange black stripes.

I tried to increase the fluid resolution to 300, but it didn't resolve this issue.

[image: Initial attempt]

The skyblue background is composed of 3 planes. I thought open space in other three axis could be a cause, so I put that cylinder in a cube, so that it resides in a closed area.

[image: 2nd attempt]

Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem neither.

Does anyone have an idea what causes this problem? I would really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your container is not properly scaled:
[image]

CTRL + A with your Container object selected, then apply Scale: no more black stripes.
[image]

Please note: in the image below I turned off object FluidDomaain for more clarity.

[image]

Sorry for poor english

Comment: Thank you for your valuable tip, but it didn't resolve the issue. With 'FluidDomain', the stripes are still there. https://imgur.com/fJrkXNM And your English is okay :D

Comment: I prevented 'InitialWater' and 'FluidDomain' to be rendered and it shows clear glass bottle now. While I can turn off 'InitialWater', 'FluidDomain' is quite important for me. It seems like those two materials are interfering...